# MySQL Trigger to update count after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need some help with a mysql trigger. I am currently trying to tidy up some code and offload some processing to the mysql database rather than running 2 queries and joins etc...

When someone inserts into a video into a database, I would like the video count in the category to update.

So you specify the category id.

This is what I have so far so any help would be good as i just dont seem to be able to get the syntax correct.

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'db_videos'.'update_video_count'
AFTER INSERT ON 'videos' FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE video_cat WHERE video_count = video_count + 1 WHERE video_cat = video_cat;
END;
```

Comment: This query is not valid, and even if it was it wouldn't do anything. In your where clause you have a condition to check for `video count = video count + 1`. This is like trying to do a SQL select `WHERE 0 = 1`. Please post the DDL for your videos table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause is duplicated and ambiguous. If I understand your data model correct, try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'db_videos'.'update_video_count'
AFTER INSERT ON 'videos' FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE video_cat vc 
      WHERE video_count = video_count + 1 
      and NEW.video_cat = vc.video_cat;
END;
```

Comment: A `SET` is missing and this `WHERE` always has zero hits (video_count ≠ video_count+1).

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'db_videos'.'update_video_count'
AFTER INSERT ON 'videos' FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE video_cat vc 
      SET video_count = video_count + 1 
      WHERE NEW.video_cat = vc.video_cat;
END;
```