# rails update_all fields and increment count by 1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a column in my mysql table called download_count of type int.

Now I want to use update_all to update some fields with some values, but also increment the download_count along with it.

I have tried the following syntax:

```
find_record.update_all(username: username, download_date: download_date, "download_count= download_count + 1")
```

But I beleive the above acts like a where clause. So the download_count does not get updated.
I want the username, download_date and the download_count to be updated by the above query.

Can someone point me to the correct syntax?

Comment: This is where you should to use SQL `TRIGGER` statement, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113808/mysql-trigger-to-update-count-after-insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, which wouldn't *by pass the validations and callbacks*.

```
User.find_each do |u| 
  u.update_attributes(
                      username: username, 
                      download_date: download_date, 
                      download_count: u.download_count + 1
                     )
end
```

Read the documentation of this [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) method to know why it is *efficient*. I took, `User` as a example name of a *model*; you use your one.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
find_record.update_all(["username=?, download_date=?, download_count=download_count+1", username, download_date])
```

Second argument to `update_all` is a condition.

Comment: The only problem is, it will _by pass_ the _validations_ and _callbacks_.

Comment: Thanks Vimsha, since it will bypass the validations and callbacks I have chosen to use find_each as suggested by Arup